# What does "interdisciplinary" mean in the context of Quantum Computing?

Tags: terminology

How is the word "*interdisciplinary*" defined and understood in the context of Quantum Computing research?

It seems many work groups are claiming ownership without even proper understanding the scope Quantum Computing embraces within its ecosystem.

Comment: The first part of the question's pretty straightforward, though what do you mean by "_It seems many work groups are claiming ownership without even proper understanding the scope Quantum Computing embraces within its ecosystem._"?

Comment: What would be the list of recommended courses that would represent cohesive enough to be eligible to comprehend the vast dimension that the QC applied research covers and attempting to cover in the immediate future.

Answer (score 5):

"interdisciplinary" is just a 'buzzword' that essentially means that none of the traditional divisions of the sciences applies for the field. As this is the case with most recent serious research, this word is often vacuous.

As for quantum computing, practice is currently dominated by the Physicists. Theory is mostly for the CS people. They don't mix very well, as both think they know the other field while they in fact don't.